# How to add scalax.io as dependency in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I want to use `scalax.io._` to manipulate file operations with SBT.

When I ran it, I got the error message showing `scalax is not found`.

```
>sbt run
import scalax.io._
[error]        ^
[error] iotest.scala:49: not found: object scalax
```

How to find the library dependency for this particular one?

A more general question, how to obtain the library dependency information for any library?
For example, if I need use actor in scala, I need specify a library dependency. How to find the library dependency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"the library dependency information for any library"* is part of the library's documentation and the author(s) is supposed to publish the info for different project management tools, sbt including. After all, what would be the purpose of developing a library that's hard to use?

Use http://search.maven.org/ to search for a library, and when you search for `scala-io` you'll get a list of available `scala-io` libraries.

Since I've never worked with the library I copied the *ScalaIOExample* example from [Scala IO Documentation](http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.4.2/index.html#!/overview) to have a working example. It needs the `scalax.io` and `scalax.file` packages that are distributed as `scala-io-file` artifact. Searching for the artifact leads to [Artifact Details For com.github.scala-incubator.io:scala-io-file_2.10:0.4.2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.scala-incubator.io%7Cscala-io-file_2.10%7C0.4.2%7Cjar) with information on how to use it with Scala SBT in *Dependency Information* section.

With this, I created the following `build.sbt` in a sbt project:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.scala-incubator.io" %% "scala-io-file" % "0.4.2"
```

It will add [scala-io-file_2.10-0.4.2.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/github/scala-incubator/io/scala-io-file_2.10/0.4.2/) to classpath and executing run in the project gives the following results:

```
$ sbt run
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-scala-io/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-scala-io (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/sbt-scala-io/)
[info] Running ScalaIOExample
Not interrupting system thread Thread[Keep-Alive-Timer,8,system]
Not interrupting system thread Thread[Keep-Alive-SocketCleaner,8,system]
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed Dec 31, 2013 11:16:42 PM
```